# Digits in Eclipse's console after HTTP status codes

Tags: python, django, eclipse, http, pydev

I am a programming newbie, and I recently installed Python + Django, and successfully created a very small web app. Everything works fine, but I am puzzled about 4 digits that appear after HTTP status codes in Eclipse's console following any request I make to my server.

Example: [27/Aug/2013 22:53:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1305

What does 1305 represent here and in every other request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the size of the response, in bytes.

Note that this has nothing to do with Eclipse, it's just the way Django's `runserver` formats its output.